# removing constant trend in dicekriging

Tags: r

I wanted to remove the constant trend by having "-1" in the formula inpu

```
design = sin(rnorm(5))
obs = rnorm(5)
model <- km(formula = ~ -1 + sin(x), design = data.frame(x = design),
            response = obs, covtype = "gauss")
model  # shows the model
```

The output is

```
Call:
km(formula = ~-1 + sin(x), design = data.frame(x = design), response = obs, 
    covtype = "gauss")

Trend  coeff.:
                Estimate
 (Intercept)    -0.1000
      sin(x)     0.8544

Covar. type  : gauss 
Covar. coeff.:
           Estimate
theta(x)     0.0000

Variance estimate: 0.7597348
```

The constant trend is still present (shown by the intercept estimate). Is there any way to remove the trend in DiceKriging?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: In R, -1 in formula means 'assume zero intercept'. Don't know if same holds for `km`.

Comment: maybe you can just substract that constant, and then add model without intercept?

Comment: Setting `coef.trend = 0` in `km` might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about a formula with other regression term besides the intercept? for example: km(formula = ~ -1 + sin(x)...

Answer (score 0):

I have had some experience with DiceKriging

Modify your code such that

```
design = sin(rnorm(5))
obs = rnorm(5)
model <- km(formula = NULL, design = data.frame(x = design),
    response = obs, covtype = "gauss")
model  # shows the model
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about a formula with other regression term besides the intercept? for example: km(formula = ~ -1 + sin(x)...

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I got an error: Error in terms.default(formula, data = data) : 
  no terms component nor attribute

Comment: @user3578272 I also tried the above and got the same error.